# concatMap with interval is not working as expected

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I'm trying to understand why my code is not working what I'm expecting it to behave.

If you copy and paste the following code in https://stackblitz.com, you will see it wait 4 seconds then it displays 'aaaa' every second instead of 'bbbb' every second. Why?

```ts
import { from, of, race, timer, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, map,merge, reduce, concatMap, delay, concat, timeout, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const obs$ = interval(4000).pipe(map(() => 'aaaa'));
const obs2$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(() => 'bbbb'));
 
const result$ = obs$.pipe(concatMap(() => obs2$));
 
const subscribe = obs$.subscribe(val => console.log(val + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()));
```

Comment: `obs$` doesn't complete, so `obs2$` is never subscribed to. It's the expected behaviour. Try adding `take(5)` to the `pipe` within `obs$` to see how the behaviour changes.

Comment: @cartant if I add take(5) to the pipe within obs$, it displays 'aaaa' 5 times and stop emitting any value. The result I'm expecting to see should be: "Wait 4 second, and display 'bbbb' every second forever. So I don't understand why it's not the case

Comment: Subscribe to `result$`. That's the observable composed using `concat`.

Comment: ok thanks @cartant it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { from, of, race, timer, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { groupBy, mergeMap, toArray, map,merge, reduce, concatMap, delay, concat, timeout, catchError, take } from 'rxjs/operators';


const obs$ = interval(14000).pipe(map(() => 'aaaa'), take(5));
const obs2$ = interval(1000).pipe(map(() => 'bbbb'));

const result$ = obs$.pipe(concatMap(() => obs2$));

const subscribe = result$.subscribe(val => console.log(val + ' ' + new Date().toLocaleTimeString()));
```